# How to line up windows C# charts

Tags: c#, graph

Link to how it looks like http://puu.sh/hc4aJ/1cb4c189b0.png

I have multiple charts in my form and they can have different Y-axis labels. But when I add those different axis labels this happens. I haven't found any option to set a margin or something so that the graphs will be aligned.

Every graph has the same location and size settings.

```
chart.Size = new Size(1000, 190);
chart.Location = new Point(0, 0);
```

Anybody got a solution?

Answer (score 0):

If all chart areas are in the same chart, you can use the `AlignWithChartArea`-Property.

```
chartArea1.AlignWithChartArea = "ChartArea2";
```